# Last built apk is older

Tags: android, react-native, build, apk

I have a very strange problem with my react native app: I did the process to make an android release apk few days ago, and now, when I want to build a new apk and install it, it keeps installing an old version of this build.

I rebuilt it with `gradlew assembleRelease` and deleted the previous apk in the output folder to be sure just before. I also uninstalled it on my phone of course. When I do `react-native run-android` to install it in development mode, it's the latest version I made, but not when I install the real build with `react-native run-android --variant=release`...

Thank you

Comment: Could you delete everyting inside ```android/app/build/outputs/apk/```?

Comment: Yeah that's what I did, and it didn't work

Comment: It is most certainly a cache issue. Could you delete android/app/build completely, restart your computer and try again please?

Comment: That's what I did and it worked. Thank you